# Making grep work for 2 digits?

Tags: bash, grep

Using this code does not work because the default grep does not support more than 1 digit:

```
grep $clean_name"_"[0-81]".png"`
```

I understand that I need to use something like:

```
[0-9]
```

But I can't figure out how to actually use it to make my code work?

Comment: Grep's regular expressions are not a great tool for matching number ranges. They work on character-level, so if you really need to match 0,1,2,..9,10,11,12,...,80,81, but nothing else, you should consider all cases manually like `[0-9]|1-7][0-9]|8[0-1]`

Comment: Excuse me? Would you mind telling what exact problem are you trying to solve with `grep`?

Comment: I am trying to run my functions 81 times, for tiles that I have labelled 1-81.

Comment: for tile in `ls $out_dir | grep $clean_name"_"[0-81]".png"`
 do
  neural_style_tiled $out_dir/$tile $style $tiles_dir/$tile
 done

Comment: I see. Well, if you're ok with `grep` catching all files with two-digits numbers, then you can refer to @SahilGulati's answer below.

Comment: Do you want `for f in "${clean_name}_"{0..81}.png; do ...`?

Comment: Will that do what I was trying to do with grep? By running the loop for tiles 0 to 81? The other solution seemed to have an issue with the tiles that had a single digit number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep "someword [0-9][0-9]" filename.txt`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work better than the previous grep command I used.